# Can I use just one instance of image tag for 3 date fields in asp.net(vb) calendarextender?

Tags: vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I have a form with 3 date fields. I am using ajaxtoolkit calendarextender with image. Is it possible to use just one image tag for all the three fields or do I have to declare it for every datefield? If at all I an use just one then where will I declare it? In the begining of the form?

Thank you

Comment: You're likely not getting any responses because your question is not understandable. Are you saying you want to put the value of 3 date fields into the TAG property of another control?  If so, you could combine the value of the 3 dates (comma seperated) into the tag as a string and then parse it out later. If this is not what you are saying, then please revisit your question so it is understandable. (sorry)

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I have a form in which I am using ajaxtookkit:calendarextender for date field. I am also using image for the popup of the calendar. I have 3 date fields in the form and I was wondering if I can use the same image tag id for all three or do I have to add image tag for each datefield text box. I did try and figured out that I do need 3 different image tag for three different date fields. When I use the same image id, the other two datefields did not display the calendar. Thanks Steve.

Comment: Put your comment as the answer and and mark it answered to get it off the "Unanswered" list.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for not being clear. I have a form in which I am using ajaxtookkit:calendarextender for date field. I am also using image for the popup of the calendar. I have 3 date fields in the form and I was wondering if I can use the same image tag id for all three or do I have to add image tag for each datefield text box. I did try and figured out that I do need 3 different image tag for three different date fields. When I use the same image id, the other two datefields did not display the calendar. Thanks Steve.